# Trying to match a variable to a filed in an array and return a result

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to programming so please forgive me if this is a dumb question or been answered before.

I have a variable that is coming from a server that identifies a city code (ex. PHO). I also have a list of objects..

```
Cities [] = [
{label: "Phoenix", code: "PHO"},
{label: "Chicago", code: "CHI"}
];
```

I need to match the city code I get from the server (PHO) to the list and return the label "Phoenix". Any help would be appreciated I just need to be pushed in the right direction.

Comment: I guess you are not using `Java` language, right?

Comment: It's an angular app I'm working on so its typescript but a lot of the code we use is Java.. the city code we receive is from a Java application. Looking at the code other people have used here looks like Java. So I'm not sure exactly if I should be using a Java method or not. I'm clearly lost.

Answer (score 0):

Simply write a function that maps your input code to an output label.

```
getCity(code: String) {
    for (let city of this.cities) {
        if (city.code == code) {
            return city.label;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

with `cities` being defined as

```
cities = [
    {label: "Phoenix", code: "PHO"},
    {label: "Chicago", code: "CHI"}
];
```

The function has linear time complexity *O(n)*, if you use a map-like structure you can improve it to *O(1)* by mapping each code to a label.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function to find the matching object in the array (assuming there is only one).

Here's an example `getLabelByCode` function.

```js
var cities = [
  { label: "Phoenix", code: "PHO" },
  { label: "Chicago", code: "CHI" }
];

function getLabelByCode(code) {
  const city = cities.find(c => c.code === code);
  if (city) {
    return city.label;
  }
  return 'NO LABEL FOUND';
}

var result = getLabelByCode("PHO");
console.log('The result is', result);
```

Alternatively you could use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) if you need to match multiple objects in the array.

Answer (score 0):

With ES7

```
const getCityByCode = code =>
    Object.values(cities).find(city =>
        city.code === code
    )

const phoenix = getCityByCode("PHO")
```

Use `phoenix.label` to get the `label` property.